# Visual Code Studio Pylint: Unable to import 'pyttsx3

Tags: python, pylint

Im running python and visual studio code on Mac when I try to import these packages:

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import pyjokes
import pywhatkit
import pyowm
```

It give me this:

```
Unable to import 'speech_recognition'
Unable to import 'wikipedia'
Unable to import 'pyjokes'
Unable to import 'pywhatkit'
Unable to import 'pyowm'
```

It says the same thing for all the packages, How do I fix This?

Comment: All of the above are third-party packages (i.e. they are not part of Standard Library) and need to be installed. Did yo install them?

Comment: Have you tried installing them manually using pip?